# Increasing an IntField within MongoEngine

Tags: python, pymongo, mongoengine

I have a model within Django with MongoEngine and would like to increment the field by 1 each time I update starting from 0

My model looks like this,

```
import mongoengine

class Fix(mongoengine.Document):
    number = mongoengine.StringField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    count = mongoengine.IntField()
```

Im using the following to update, but not sure how to set it to 0 to start and also increment by 1,

```
Fix.objects(number="number").modify(upsert=True, new=True,set__count=???)
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `inc_count` like this:

```
Fix.objects(device_number="number").modify(upsert=True, new=True,inc__count=1)
```

This would increment `count` by `1` atomically.

For setting to `0`, you can use a default value to `0` on your model. Also the increment should assume 0 if no value is set.